# How to interpret assignment to pointer in C

Tags: c, pointers, operators, declaration, dereference

In C, the statement `int *var_name;` by convention means that `*var_name` is of type `int`, which implies that `var_name` is an integer pointer.

But now consider this sequence of statements.

```
int a = 5;
int *var_name = &a;
```

But here how are we assigning address of `a` to `*var_name` which is of type `int`?

Comment: You are not assigning the address of a to `*var_name` you are assigning the address of a to `var_name`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/562303/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list I'd suggest taking a look at this list and picking a book from the "beginner" section

Comment: Most of the confusion about pointers in C come from using the same `*` syntax during declaration and de-referencing. It's easier to simply not mix up these two concepts at all. (Same syntax confusion exists between declaring an array of size n but de-referencing it from index 0 to n-1.)

Comment: @Lundin yes. This is quite confusing. I see there is another way to interpret it. `int* var_name` would mean `var_name` is a pointer to an `int` and then the assignment of `var_name` with an address would make sense.

Comment: `int*` is the type of the variable and this literally means "pointer to int".

Comment: You might find [this section](https://www.eskimo.com/~scs/cclass/notes/sx10a.html) of some online C notes useful, especially its last few paragraphs, beginning with "Finally, a few more notes about pointer declarations".

Comment: Context is everything. The two lines of code are *not* statements, they are *declarations* (and also definitions). The `=` is not the assignment operator, it is part of the syntax for a declaration with an initializer. The `*` to the left of the `=` is not the indirection operator (and is not the multiplication operator either), it is part of the declared type of the variable. The part to the right of the `=` in the declaration is the initializer for the variable.

Answer (score 3):

You are not assigning the address to `*var_name`, but to `var_name`. And this variable is of type "pointer to `int`", as you found.

Oh, and it is an initialization, not an assignment.

Answer (score 0):

That's just the way the syntax in C works.

```
int *p = &a;
```

is completely equivalent to:

```
int *p;
p = &a;
```

It's not so difficult to understand why it would not make sense if it worked the way you thought. Consider this code:

```
int *p;
p = &a;
*p = 42;
```

Now imagine flipping the last two statements, like this:

```
int *p;
*p = 42; // To which address do we write 42? p is not initialized.
p = &a;
```

So although the meaning of `int *p = &a;`, which is `int *p; p = &a;` might be unintuitive, it's actually the only sane way to define it.

Comment: And neither works in case `a` is declared as `int a;`.

Comment: @Lundin True. Didn't intentionally copy the name of the variable. Just thought of a as in address, like I did with p as in pointer. Fixed it now.

Answer (score 0):

In this declaration:

```
int *var_name = &a;
```

there is declared the variable var_name of the pointer type `int *` and this variable (pointer) is initialized by the address of the variable `a`.

It seems you mixing the symbol `*` in declarations and in expressions.

In declarations it denotes a pointer. In expressions it denotes the dereference operator.

Consider the following demonstration program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( void )
{
    int a = 5;
    int *var_name = &a;

    printf( "The address stored in var_name is %p\n", ( void * )var_name );
    printf( "The address of the variable a  is %p\n", ( void * )&a );

    printf( "The value of the object pointed to by var_name is %d\n", *var_name );
    printf( "The value stored in the variable a is %d\n", a );
}
```

Its output might look like

```
The address stored in var_name is 00EFFAC0
The address of the variable a  is 00EFFAC0
The value of the object pointed to by var_name is 5
The value stored in the variable a is 5
```

That is in this line:

```
    int *var_name = &a;
```

`*var_name` means a declarator of a pointer type.

In this call:

```
printf( "The value of the object pointed to by var_name is %d\n", *var_name );
```

`*var_name` means an expression with the dereference operator `*`.